# DB2 linking schemas across multiple instances

Tags: database, db2, database-schema, multiple-instances, db2-luw

I have a few instances of DB2 10.5 server running on one physical Linux machine, let name them INST1 and INST2.

All of them contain multiple schemas, however schema-naming is unique accross whole machine, for example 
    INST1_SCHEMA_A, 
    INST2_SCHEMA_A etc.

What I would like to do is to somehow create a user that can access all of those schemas as they were on one instance, so it would be possible to make a queries like:
    SELECT ID 
      FROM INST1_SCHEMA_A 
    UNION 
    SELECT ID 
    FROM INST2_SCHEMA_A

How can I achieve that? Should I just link databases and alias schemas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Federation

is the keyword for your request. DB2 LUW to DB2 LUW is included in the license and this could be done across multiple databases - not matter if they reside within the same instance, another instance on the same server or even a different server.

Set FEDERATED = YES in the DBM CFG, define a server and set up Nicknames for remote tables.  For details refer to this [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0203haas/0203haas.html) or this [one](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/db2luwtechsupport/entry/how_to_setup_federation_between_two_db2_luw_databases2?lang=en) or the IBM Knowledge Center.

Comment: You need to define a SERVER as localhost in order to access the other instance. You could even access another database in the same instance with federation.

Comment: Thank you, I switched and configured FEDERATED mode. Almost everything works. Only thing that I do not know how to configure are sequences - how to CREATE NICKNAME for them if the `db2 CREATE NICKNAME SCHEMA.SEQ_NAME FOR SERVER_NAME.SCHEMA.SEQ_NAME` says `SQL0204N  "SERVER_NAME.SCHEMA.SEQ_NAME" is an undefined name.  SQLSTATE=42704`?