# DB2 federation and sequences

Tags: database, db2, sequence, federation

I have federated DB2 instance where I join data from different tables from other DB2 instances (by creating nicknames for all elements) as mentioned in my previous question: [DB2 linking schemas across multiple instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38185569/db2-linking-schemas-across-multiple-instances)

However currently I have a problem with federating user-defined sequences. At source instance I can easily do queries like `VALUES NEXT VALUE FOR SCHEMA.SEQUENCE_NAME` but on federated instance `VALUES NEXT VALUE FOR SERVER_NAME.SCHEMA.SEQUENCE_NAME` throws `SQLCODE=-204` and  `SQLSTATE=42704 - undefined name`.

Any idea how to access those sequences?

Any ideas how to nickname or get to those remote

Answer (score 1):

You can't federate a sequence object – you can only federate Tables/Views and Stored Procedures.

However, you can issue the `SET PASSTHRU <server>` statement, which will send SQL statements you execute directly to the remote server:

```
SET PASSTHRU SERVER_NAME;
VALUES NEXTVAL for SCHEMA.SEQUENCE_NAME;
SET PASSTHRU RESET;
```

Comment: Thank you, but is there any way to make it more transparent - just like nicknames for tables?

Comment: As I said in my answer, *you can't federate a sequence object*.  So, no.